# Ruby, get incoming address from UDP message

Tags: ruby, sockets

I have a UDP server that binds to all addresses on a system, I would like to know what ip address the message was addressed to.  Any ideas how to do this?

Here is my example code:

```
sock = Socket.new(Socket::AF_INET, Socket::SOCK_DGRAM, 0)
sock.bind(Addrinfo.udp('', 2400))
while(true)
    sockset = IO.select([sock])
    sockset[0].each do |sock|
        data = sock.recvfrom(1024)
        puts "data: " + data.inspect
    end
end
sock.close
```

This will produce something like:

> data: ["test message\n", #`<`Addrinfo: 172.16.5.110:41949 UDP>]

Am I able to set a socket option, or something, to return the local IP?

Just a note, this needs to work for IPv6 too.  Thanks in advance, Dave.

Comment: But isn't `172.16.5.110` the local IP in your example?

Answer (score 2):

[*UNIX Network Programming*](http://www.unpbook.com/) has this to say about this very subject:

> With a UDP socket, however, the destination IP address can only be obtained by setting the `IP_RECVDSTADDR` socket option for IPv4 or the `IPV6_PKTINFO` socket option for IPv6 and then calling `recvmsg` instead of `recvfrom`.

Ruby’s socket library has [`recvmsg`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/socket/rdoc/BasicSocket.html#method-i-recvmsg) which is a bit easier to use than the underlying C function, but still needs a bit of work to get the info needed. The destination IP address is included in the array of ancillary data returned from `recvmsg`. Here’s a version of your code adapted to use `recvmsg` and get the destination address for IPv4:

```
require 'socket'
require 'ipaddr'

sock = Socket.new(Socket::AF_INET, Socket::SOCK_DGRAM, 0)

# Set the required socket option:
sock.setsockopt :IPPROTO_IP, :IP_RECVDSTADDR, true
sock.bind(Addrinfo.udp('0.0.0.0', 2400))

while(true)
    sockset = IO.select([sock])
    sockset[0].each do |sock|

        mesg, sender, _, *anc_data = sock.recvmsg

        # Find the relevant data and extract it into a string
        dest = IPAddr.ntop(anc_data.find {|d| d.cmsg_is?(:IP, :RECVDSTADDR)}.data)

        puts "Data: #{mesg}, Sender: #{sender.ip_address}, Destination: #{dest}"

    end
end
```

And here is a version for IPv6. There is also a `RECVPKTINFO` socket option, which I think may have superseded `PKTINFO` – depending on your system you may need to use that instead.

```
require 'socket'

sock = Socket.new(Socket::AF_INET6, Socket::SOCK_DGRAM, 0)

# Set the socket option for IP6:
sock.setsockopt :IPPROTO_IPV6, :IPV6_PKTINFO, true

sock.bind(Addrinfo.udp('0::0', 2400))

while(true)
    sockset = IO.select([sock])
    sockset[0].each do |sock|

        mesg, sender, _, *anc_data = sock.recvmsg

        # Find and extract the destination address
        dest = anc_data.find {|d| d.cmsg_is?(:IPV6, :PKTINFO)}.ipv6_pktinfo_addr

        puts "Data: #{mesg}, Sender: #{sender.ip_address}, Destination: #{dest.ip_address}"
    end
end
```

Ruby also provides a [`Socket.udp_server_loop` method](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/socket/rdoc/Socket.html#method-c-udp_server_loop), which yields the message and  a [`UDPSource`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/socket/rdoc/Socket/UDPSource.html) object to the block you provide, and this source object has a `local_address` field. [Looking at the source](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_1_2/ext/socket/lib/socket.rb#L679) this appears to check the `PKTINFO` data like I do above to get the destination address for IPv6 requests, but not for IPv4. This method binds to all available IP addresses individually, and just uses the address of the incoming interface for IP4 requests, which may not be accurate for a [weak end system model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_model). However it might be simpler for you to use `Socket.udp_server_loop`.

Comment: A caveat: I’m not really able to test this properly since I only have a single system available. It _seems_ to be correct, but I would be keen to hear confirmation or disagreements.

Comment: anc_data is coming as an empty array. Any workaround for that???